# React set min-height property of element with specific className

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React Component where on `componentDidMount()' I want to set the`min-height`property of an element where`className="content-wrapper"` to '600px'.

I have tried the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('content-wrapper').style.minHeight = "600px"
}
```

Unfortunately that results in the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'minHeight' of undefined
>
> at MyComponent.componentDidMount

I'm still getting the hang of React and would appreciate any help possible in achieving this goal. Thanks!

Comment: Is content-wrapper an element that you have created in a react component or just using standard html or js?

Comment: It was just a `div` tag

Comment: Well, if you created this `div` tag in a react component then it will be a virtual `div`. In this case the accepted answer isn't what you want because you are directly modifying the DOM which isn't good. If it's a div in a normal html file or created using normal JS then it's fine.

Comment: What do you recommend?  The accepted answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted how you created content-wrapper still.

If you did something like this:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="content-wrapper"/>
    }
}
```

Then modifying the DOM directly goes against React (even though it may work) because React uses a virtual DOM to see what has changed since last render. Therefore if you modify the DOM directly, React will overwrite these changes because it's looking at the previous virtual DOM and thinks nothing changed.

Instead you will want:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
       this.setState({conentWrapperMinHeight: "600px"})
   }
   render() {
       return <div className="content-wrapper" style={{minHeight: this.state.conentWrapperMinHeight}} />
 }
}
```

You could just hardcode 600px in if you do it for 1 div only or you could dynamically add a class to content-wrapper and set minHeight in css to 600px.

If you have multi content-wrapper div's that you want to change in multiple components then you will need to [lift the state up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a higher component and pass it down as props or use Redux or Flux if they are completely unrelated.

Comment: I only have the one content-wrapper `div` so it's fine, but thanks.  If what you say is true and this is better practice then I appreciate your answer and efforts.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Even if it's just one div, if it's a **virtual** div then you want to hardcode the value like `style={{minHeight: "600px"}}` and not through the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Get elements, iterate and set style.

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.content-wrapper').forEach(el => el.style.minHeight = '600px');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also manipulate the DOM node directly using ReactDOM. Using TypeScript (but applicable to JS as well of course):

```
private setMinHeight = () => {
    const thisNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this) as HTMLElement;
    if (thisNode) {
        thisNode.style.minHeight = (...);
    }
}
```

This function may be called in `componentDidMount()`, and, if you want it to update min-height every time the component is re-rendered, in `componentDidUpdate()` as well.